# Laravel 4.2 not working recursive on boot

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

For example I have three models:

**`Invoice`** : has many cards

**`Card`** : has many serviceLogs

**`ServiceLog`**

```
class Invoice extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "invoice";
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
    protected $deleted_at = ['deleted_at'];

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        Invoice::deleted(function($invoice) {
            if ($invoice->cards()) {
                if ($invoice->forceDeleting) {
                    $invoice->cards()->forceDelete();
                } else {
                    $invoice->cards()->delete();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function cards() {
        return $this->hasMany("Card");
    }
}

class Card extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "card";
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
    protected $deleted_at = ['deleted_at'];

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        Card::deleted(function($card) {
            if ($card->serviceLogs()) {
                if ($card->forceDeleting) {
                    $card->serviceLogs()->forceDelete();
                } else {
                    $card->serviceLogs()->delete();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function serviceLogs() {
        return $this->hasMany("ServiceLog");
    }
}


class ServiceLog extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "service_log";
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
    protected $deleted_at = ['deleted_at'];

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

}
```

When an $invoice is deleted, the boot() function of Invoice model automatically deletes all the cards that associate with.

But the boot() function of Card model not firing after a $card has been deleted from the function above.

So that all $serviceLogs that associate with each $card has not been deleted too.

My question is how to delete recursive in Laravel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call the `delete()` function on each Card model itself. At the moment you are calling it on the collection of models, which doesn't result in the boot method of each model being called.

instead do:

```
$forceDeleting = $invoice->forceDeleting;
$invoice->cards->each(function($model) use($forceDeleting){
    if ($forceDeleting) {
        $model->forceDelete();
    } else {
        $model->delete();
    }
});
```

Similarly if your ServiceLog model also has a boot method you want to get fired, you will need to follow the same approach in the Card `::deleted()` boot method, and iterate over each Card and call `delete()` on each individual model.